# Is there a possibility to turn off the automatic enclosing of all written content within <p></p> in tinymce

Tags: tinymce

Is there a possibility to turn off the automatic enclosing of all written content within `<p>` tag in TinyMCE

My output is like below in paragraph tags

```
<P>SAMPLE</P>
```

Comment: Something went terribly wrong with your caps lock key.

Comment: yaa..my problem is after entering data into tinymce while retriving data it is displaying inside the paragraph tags how can i resolve this problem

Answer (score 1):

Use `forced_root_block:false`

> This option enables you to make sure that any non block elements or
>   text nodes are wrapped in block elements. For example
>   <strong>something</strong> will result in output like:
>   <p><strong>something</strong></p>. This option is enabled by default
>   as of version 3.0a1.
>
> If you set this option to false it will never produce p tags on enter,
>   or, automatically it will instead produce br elements and Shift+Enter
>   will produce a p.
>
> Note that not using p elements as root block can severely cripple the
>   functionality of the editor.

See: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#forced_root_block